# brcmfmac sdio error: it's software or hardware fault?

Tags: wifi, embedded, yocto

I'm working on a custom embedded board that embeds a BCM43430 (from Cypress). The os is a customized Yocto project for an armv7l-based MPU.
On boot I get these messages:

```
# dmesg | grep brcm
[   11.532101] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   12.114032] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   12.203900] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Sep 11 2018 09:22:09 version 7.45.98.65 (r707797 CY) FWID 01-b54727f
[   30.919833] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_kso_control: max tries: rd_val=0x0 err=0
[   30.936034] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   30.953493] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   30.960298] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   30.970906] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   30.978032] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   31.012996] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
```

And of course the wifi is not working.
I've checked the `iw dev wlan0 info`:

```
# iw dev wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr dc:ef:ca:12:22:1a
    type managed
    wiphy 0
```

and:

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
brcmfmac              192512  0
cfg80211              503808  1 brcmfmac
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
ipv6                  417792  34
```

Because the error messages talks about "tx failures" and "sdio" (related to I/O?) U wonder if the issue is hardware-side or software-side.

What should I further check to find the root cause of the problem?

### UPDATE

It seems it looks for the `sdio` bus on the wrong one:

```
brcmfmac: probe of mmc0:0001:2 failed with error -62
```

but the WiFi transceiver is actually connected on a different `mmcX' bus.
Where can I change this setting?

Comment: What is your kernel version?

Comment: @GAD3R the kernel version is 4.19.49